# How to represent a location of an object in an image mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, programming

So, let's say I have two matrices, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, each of dimensions $l*l*256$. $\mathbf{B}$ is a warped version of $\mathbf{A}$. Which means there is some matrix, $\mathbf{H}$ (popularly called a homography matrix in the computer vision community) that allows me to map $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{B}$. Essentially, this means I have a feature map (as it's popularly known in the AI world) of dimensions $l*l$ and depth of $256$.

Now, let's say there are a set of pixel locations in $A$ that are "interesting." I call this set $K$, keypoints. If I apply my homography matrix to $k$ where $k \in K$, I get $k' = \mathbf{H}k$. I define $\mathbf{d_k}$ as a vector containing all the values of $\mathbf{A}$ along the third dimension at the pixel location of $k$. Likewise, $\mathbf{d_k'}$ represents all the values of $\mathbf{B}$ along the 3rd dimension at pixel location $k'$.

So finally, I'm defining a loss function as follows:

$$L = \frac{\sum^K_k{l_d(d_k, d_k')}}{|K|}$$
$$l_d(\mathbf{d}, \mathbf{d'}) = \text{max}(0, m_p - \mathbf{d^T}\mathbf{d'})$$

My questions are the following.

1. How can I properly describe $d_k$ mathematically instead of having to be so verbose?
2. Is everything else I stated also sound? Particularly when I'm bolding and not bolding things.

My explanation of this function will be reviewed by mathematically rigorous people. Hence, as much as scrutiny as possible would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be using the word, *matrix*, in a nonstandard way. All the matrices I know have two dimensions, not three.

Comment: You should be careful to distinguish what you’re calling the “matrices” $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf B$, which appear to me to be arrays of pixel values (i.e., arrays of values sampled from two image planes) from the transformation matrix $\mathbf H$, which represents a homography between two continuous planes. To obtain $\mathbf B$ from $\mathbf A$ via $\mathbf H$ you will in general need to somehow resample or interpolate pixel values.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Perhaps, I should use the word "tensor?"

Comment: @amd so A is 256 feature maps in actuality. But the way I'm using it is as a tensor such that the channel-wise values represent descriptors of the pixel at that particular location. Is that what you mean by array of values sampled from two image planes? If not, I'm not quire sure how I can show "resample or interpolate pixel values."

Comment: Before what you decide to call it, I think you should work out what you mean by writing that $H$ allows you to map $A$ to $B$. What kind of thing is $H$? An array of numbers? a two-dimensional array? a three-dimensional array? in what way does it allow you to map $A$ to $B$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $H$ is a 3x3 matrix (not tensor). It's a homography matrix, better explained here: https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/